# Load A Chinese Web (CHM) url using UIWebView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, chm, cjk

I am trying to use UIWebView to load a Chinese web url. If I encode it with utf-8 then it becomes:

`html/libfunctions/%CA%FD%D7%E9%B9%DC%C0%ED(Array).htm -- xchm://03000000-0A00-0400-F25E-D84B09001600/` which cannot be loaded from UIWebView.

If I try to put it using the default one of Chinese: `html/libfunctions/录脝脢卤脝梅鹿脺脌铆(Timers).htm`, then the

```
NSString *urlString = @"html/libfunctions/录脝脢卤脝梅鹿脺脌铆(Timers).htm";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

will give me a nil url. Does anybody know how can I load a Chinese web url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`? Pass it the encoding for the string and it should give you a valid URL which will change to Chinese characters when transferred to a broswer.

EDIT: Use that function only on the Chinese part of your url, then concatenate the "http://www." part.